# MoviePy animated text

Tags: python, moviepy

How can I make that the text goes and don't stop at the left side?
I don't see the problem with the method I used. And I think i used the right formula for the Animation.

```
from moviepy.editor import *

# Load video
video = VideoFileClip("auto.mp4")

# Video lenght
duration = video.duration

# Video size
w, h = video.size

# Load text from txt
f = open('data.txt', 'r')
data = f.read().replace('\n', '')

# Text for video
txt = (TextClip(data, fontsize=50, font='Amiri-regular',
                color='white')
       .set_duration(duration))

# Transparent text background
txt_col = txt.on_color(size=(video.w + txt.w, txt.h - 10),
                       color=(0, 0, 0), pos=(6, 'center'), col_opacity=0.8)

# Animate text
txt_mov = txt_col.set_pos(lambda t: (max(w / w, int(w - 0.5 * w * t)),
                                     max(5.4 * h / 6, int(0 * t))))

# Overlay text on video
result = CompositeVideoClip([video, txt_mov])
# Render video
result.write_videofile("test.mp4")
```

Comment: maybe create normal function instead of `lambda` and add `print()` to see if you calculate correct values. Maybe it will need to add/substract length of string - and you will need `w + txt.width` instead of `w` or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code works for me when I use

```
 int(w - 0.5 * w * t)
```

instead of

```
 max(w/w, int(w - 0.5 * w * t))
```

So `max(w/w, ...)` was stoping animation

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you will like it:

```
#for ticker remove -0.2
 
max(w / 2.5, int(-0.2 * w * t)),  
max(h * 4 / 10, int(10 * t)))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Consider explaining why this code solves the problem